# Combining different list types to work in one document

Tags: enumerate, enumitem, inline

I would like to use `\usepackage{enumerate}` to write lists using both 1., 2., 3., and A., B., C.  However, in some of my lists, I would like to save space in my paper and write, say, the first 3 items in one line and the next 2 items in the line following.

I saw that I could use `\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}` to do the latter, but then it messes up my lists containing A., B., C.

Is it possible to use both in one paper?

Below are examples of the 3 types of lists I would like to use in the minimal code needed to work. The first two work in one code, but the last will not work in the same paper as the first two.

```
\documentclass{article}
%This is for the first list
\usepackage{enumerate}


%This is for the second list.
% To list numbers/tasks in form of columns to save space.
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}[2013/04/07]
% renew the {tasks} environment to use bold labels
% and use two columns as default settings:
\RenewTasks[counter-format= tsk.,label-format=\bfseries]{tasks}(1)


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[A.]
\item Method 1.

\item Method 2.

\item Method 3 uses the following 3 operations.
    \begin{enumerate}[1.]\label{rowops}
    \item Operation 1.
    \item Operation 2.
    \item Operation 3.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\vspace{1em}

\begin{multicols}{1}
\noindent Properties of $D$
\begin{tasks}
\task Property 1,
\task Property 2,
\task Property 3,
\task Property 4,
\task Property 5.
\end{tasks}

\noindent Properties of $A = B$
\begin{tasks}
\task Property 1,
\task Property 2,
\task Property 3,
\task Property 4,
\task Property 5.
\end{tasks}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

The `\inlineitem` is used below to list more than 1 item in a row, but this code does not work with the code above.  Any advice or assistance is appreciated towards getting all three types of lists in one document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}   
\makeatletter
% This command ignores the optional argument for itemize and enumerate lists
\newcommand{\inlineitem}[1][]{%
\ifnum\enit@type=\tw@
    {\descriptionlabel{#1}}
  \hspace{\labelsep}%
\else
  \ifnum\enit@type=\z@
       \refstepcounter{\@listctr}\fi
    \quad\@itemlabel\hspace{\labelsep}%
\fi}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}  % Combined inline list
\item Item $1$, \inlineitem Item $2$,\inlineitem Item $3$,
\item Item $4$,\label{thm1.4} \inlineitem Item $5$.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of loading the `enumerate` package, use the `shortlabels` option of `enumitem` to emulate that format.  Then you can combine your inline item with an enumerate-type list. Unless you are using the actual inline lists (`enumerate*` etc.) of `enumitem` you don't need the `inline` option for this code to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}   
\makeatletter
% This command ignores the optional argument for itemize and enumerate lists
\newcommand{\inlineitem}[1][]{%
\ifnum\enit@type=\tw@
    {\descriptionlabel{#1}}
  \hspace{\labelsep}%
\else
  \ifnum\enit@type=\z@
       \refstepcounter{\@listctr}\fi
    \quad\@itemlabel\hspace{\labelsep}%
\fi}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[A.]  % Combined inline list
\item Item $1$, \inlineitem Item $2$,\inlineitem Item $3$,
\item Item $4$,\label{thm1.4} \inlineitem Item $5$.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```